# How to cat string with list objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string which I want to concatenate with every object within a list. Here is an example:

```
a = ['1','2']
b = 'a'
```

and I want:

```
c = ['a1','a2']
```

It seems that strings can't be concatenated to list objects directly so I assume that I should convert my list to the string and then add it. Is it correct or any suggestions?

Comment: why the downvote? perfectly legitimate question. upvoting to compensate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Python [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

```
>>> a = ['1','2']
>>> b = 'a'
>>> [b+i for i in a]
['a1', 'a2']
```